# SSRS - Remove Duplicate Date in a Date Range Parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to remove duplicate dates in the date range parameters.  I have found a VB code block online for removing text duplicates.  I believe that a slight modification on the codes will solve my problem.  However, apologies in advance that I am a newbie in VBC and I am having a hard time to modify the codes.  Please help Thank you!!!

Update:
I am using one of the columns "Ship_Date", which has duplicate values, as the values in my two parameters ("Start_Date" and "End_Date"). I am trying to contain only distinct values in the drop-down menu.

[Please click this for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7f85.png)

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(parameter As Parameter) As String()
  
Dim items As Object() = parameter.Value
System.Array.Sort(items)
Dim k As Integer = 0
  
For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then
Continue For
End If
  
items(k) = items(i)
k += 1
Next
Dim unique As [String]() = New [String](k - 1) {}
System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)
  
Return unique
End Function
```

Comment: There may be an easier way to do this but you will need to provide much more info. How are you defining the date range, is it with two SSRS parameters? How are the parameters used in your query? What is causing the duplicates in the first place? Edit your question to explain these things and there could be a simple answer, without the need for VBA functions.

Comment: If the dates are coming from a query can you not just create a dataset with a query something like `SELECT DISTINCT Ship_Date FROM myTable` and then set the parameter's available values to that query.